# How can I make the scroll thumb always visible?

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, styling

Does anyone know how to make the scroll thumb always visible? `overflow: scroll` only shows the tracks. I am currently using react if that changes anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, scrollbar behaviour is controlled by the browser. You *can* [create a styled scrollbar](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars-in-css/), but this won't work in all browsers (such as Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the scrollbar thumb for the webkit browsers so the the scroll thumb will have a custom style and it will be always visible. You can use the following CSS pseudo selectors -

```
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
```

You can [check this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) for more details.

Comment: As far as I know, this method of styling is not very flexible. Last time I remember using it I was only able to change the height, color and border-radius when my project needed the scrollbar to be positioned outside of the element which is most likely impossible with vanilla scrollbars.

Comment: But it being inflexible is not the problem, I at least couldn't find a way of making a hidden thumb visible with those pseudo-classes.